# Windows using "start"-Command: assign specific resources to thread

Tags: windows, multithreading, batch-file

I am conducting some experiments on Windows 7 to observe interference between concurrent tasks. I have a .bat file with the following code:

```
start /high ConsoleApplication1.exe
```

This creates a new thread and executes "ConsoleApplication1.exe". This thread gets assigned 25% of the total CPU, i.e. one out of four cores.

If I change my .bat file to:

```
start /high ConsoleApplication1.exe
start /high ConsoleApplication1.exe
```

then two new threads are created and executed in parallel. Each thread gets assigned 25% of the total CPU, i.e. one out of four cores. This means that in total 50% of the total CPU respectively 2 out of 4 cores are used. I can observe, as desired and expected, that it takes slightly longer to execute 2 programs in parallel than just one in isolation.

**My Question:**
I would like to create 4 threads running 4 instances of "ConsoleApplication1.exe", but each thread is only allowed to use **not more than 12.5% CPU**. So in total those 4 threads should then use ~50% of the total CPU respectively 2 out of 4 cores. Is there a simple way to manage this? Something like this?:

```
start /high ConsoleApplication1.exe CPU<= 0.125
start /high ConsoleApplication1.exe CPU<= 0.125
start /high ConsoleApplication1.exe CPU<= 0.125
start /high ConsoleApplication1.exe CPU<= 0.125
```

Thank you!

**Edit:**
After using `start /?` (thanks to Ken White) I learned that the start-command doesn't support assigning a specific amount to a thread. That means that I am looking for an alternative way (without the "start"-command) now.

Comment: You can see what's possible with *start* by using `start /?` at a command prompt.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried it out. Unfortunately it seems that start doesn't support assigning a specific amount to a thread. That means that I am looking for an alternative way (without start) now.